# Make piece of code a bit more generic or/and refactor it in order of reusing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

I have block of code which contains a lot of nested loops (I have to mention over here is that we don't have a problem with speed of the code). Now in turn on that I have to have the same functionality within the same Controller Action with all the loops again, but I don't want to just copy and paste the same code and just changing the variables over there.

The idea of the code is with the first For loop we are making requests over some API and if the response is empty we are stop sending request. Inside the loop we are reading JSON response of every calls and add it to our class:

```
var transactions = new List<Transaction>();
for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
{
    if (morePagesInXero == false)
    {
         valueCollection.Add("page", pages.ToString());
         morePages= true;
    }
    else
    {
         valueCollection.Set("page", pages.ToString());
    }

var invoices = api.GetArray(GlobalConstants.Invoices, where, null, valueCollection);
dynamic invoicesResponse=JObject.Parse(invoices.ToString());

var jsonTransactions =((JProperty((JContainer)invoicesResponse).Last).Value;
var arrayTransactions = ((JArray)jsonTransactions);
 // Check if there are more than 1 page
if (arrayTransactions.Count == 0)
{
     break;
}
else
{
    foreach (var item in jsonTransactions)
    {
        transaction.taxDirection = "DummyDataFromResponseJSON";
        transaction.invoiceNumber = "DummyData1FromResponseJSON"
        transaction.upstreamModifiedAt = "DummyData2FromResponseJSON";
        transaction.currency = "DummyData3FromResponseJSON";
        transaction.customerId = "DummyData4FromResponseJSON";
        // and so on ...
        transactions.Add(transaction);
    }
    pages++;
}
```

Now I have to make a new call to the API on different end point but the logic of manipulating the JSON response is the same one with those loops. Please advice is it possible to reuse the code above in order to make it more generic and just reuse it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the code into a method and call it from your different contexts? It´s hard to make a better suggestion with that code without the actual *calling* code.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: I have read this article about using dynamic in JSON.NET https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing